# How can i set up my geckodriver for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Im trying to do the obeythetestinggoat tutorial and cant set my geckodriver,

Im working in Win10 64bits

my pip freeze shows:

Django==1.7,selenium==3.141.0,urllib3==1.25.7

i download the geckodriver (geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64) when i try to get the geckodriver version (via `$geckodriver --version`) stops and show me a error 'application error'

I think that the error are in the enviroment variables (i was trying to put the file in location where the variables are set (windows/system32 or python/scripts) but nothing works

i also trying this solution (put the file in some file where path are viable) in another computer and works.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve it like this:

1. `pip install webdriver-manager`
2. in Python i wrote following code and run it:

   ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
   ```
3. Now add the path below to your PATH variable (of course replace **your_user_name** with the one you have there:

   `c:\users\your_user_name\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\v0.26.0\win64`

   At this point geckodriver should be visible be Selenium from Python. Note: geckodriver does not show up when you run `pip freeze`

Comment: I installed the webdriver-manager

i cant add the PATH (i cant find the dir where geckodriver are)

i try to call geckodriver (to see if the instalation was right) with '$geckodriver --version' i see that pip freeze doesnt show geckodriver. thnks for the advice.

Comment: @Tajaludo when you run the code on step 2 python will tell you where geckodriver is installed and normally goes on the path mentioned at step 3.

Comment: When i run the 3 line it shows the same Geckodriver 'application error'
and the terminal shows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\

Comment: site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\Ceron\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\v0.26.0\win64\geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595

Comment: but in the first part of the error shows: 

Looking for [geckodriver v0.26.0 win64] driver in cache
File found in cache by path [C:\Users\Ceron\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\v0.26.0\win64\geckodriver.exe]

Then explotes

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 > First You Need To Download The v0.26.0 version make sure you download for correct os if you are using window donwload for window and if you are using linux or other download fo them

STEP2 > Put the geckodirver in your python directory

Step3 > write this code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('your url')
```

Comment: i did the 3 steps i downloaded from here ( https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases )

Then i set the geckodriver en the python/scripts directory (i checked with my enviroments variables)  

when i try to use geckodriver show me a 'application error'

Comment: make sure you paste in your python directory means where you make your python file

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: Win10 the initial post has all the technical info. 

I copy the geckodriver in where i put my python file (when i delete it, stops to show that error, so i asume that it's the geckodriver) still not working.

Comment: what you delete?

Comment: the geckodriver.exe, it detects in the path only dont work

Answer (score 0):

> This question have been cropping up pretty often recently. To burst the myth, you don't need to install **geckodriver** anyway.

To set the [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver) you need to ensure a couple of things as follows:

---

### Windows 10, 64 bits

Steps:

- As the most recent *GeckoDriver* release being *v0.26.0*, you can download either of the following binaries from [**Releases - mozilla/geckodriver**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page and save it within a sub-directory on your system e.g. within `"C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers"`:

  - **`geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.zip`**: The 64-bit Windows OS compatible *GeckoDriver*
  - **`geckodriver-v0.26.0-win32.zip`**: The 32-bit Windows OS compatible *GeckoDriver*
- Unzip the **`geckodriver-v0.26.0-winXY.zip`** file and extract the **geckodriver.exe** (e.g. `"C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe"`)
- Now you can open the command prompt, change the directory and issue the following command:

  ```
  geckodriver --version
  ```
- Output:

[image: geckodriver_cmd]

---

### Usage

Now you can use the *GeckoDriver* to initiate a *Firefox Browsing session* passing the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* as an argument using the following lines of code:

- Python:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Logs/geckodriver.log')
  driver.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Java:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class A_Firefox 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah, i unzip and put in a directory, only that when i use that command (geckodriver --version) shows me the next error:   -------  -------------------------------------------------


Looking for [geckodriver v0.26.0 win64] driver in cache
File found in cache by path [C:\Users\Ceron\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\v0.26.0\win64\geckodriver.exe]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\Ceron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\Ceron\.wdm\drivers\geckodriver\v0.26.0\win64\geckodriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595

Comment: @Tajaludo Your main issue was `geckodriver --version` command showing **`application error`** for which I have constructed the answer. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: When I check geckodriver version it shows me I have and older version installed (0.14.0), even though i downloaded, extracted and added to PATH the newer version.

Comment: @NejcOsterman Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: @DebanjanB I get ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'``` with the first line: ```driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')``` because I don't know the ```log_path```. I've searched my C: drive and cannot find any ```geckodriver.log```?